# On click of button download a .sh file using filename and content using angular js and how to write the content keys in .sh file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

download .sh file using angular js with filename and content

Below  is the .sh file contains

export OS_USERNAME="lakshmi_ekula"//this is the value and getting it from response

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: var blob = new Blob([response.body.file_content], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, " "+response.body.file_name);

Comment: By using above lines Iam able to download the file with .sh extension. But I opened the file in notepad I am getting [object object]

Comment: What is in your file_content variable? [object object] is usually a sign of an improper casting to string somewhere in your code.

Comment: In content of file. I have json data like key value pair, from this data I need to render the commands in .sh file. for example                                               export OS_AUTH_URL=http://10.xxx.52.161:5000/v2.0                                http://10.xxx.52.161:5000/v2.0 is the value I am getting it from response of the conent from backend